# Fixed point combinator usage? Why a stack overflow here?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, stack-overflow, y-combinator, fixpoint-combinators

I am confused about something. I wanted to generate an example (in Clojure) demonstrating how a fixed point combinator could be used to evaluate the fixed point of a sequence that mathematically converges after an infinite number of applications but would, in fact, converge after a finite number of steps due to finite precision of floating points. I am apparently missing something here.

```
(defn Y [r]
  ((fn [f] (f f))
   (fn [f]
     (r (fn [x] ((f f) x))))))

(defn simple-convergent [func]
  (fn [x]
    (if (zero? x)
      0.0
      (* 0.5 (func x)))))
```

I can then get

```
user=> ((Y simple-convergent) 0.)
0.0
user=> ((Y simple-convergent) 0.2)
java.lang.StackOverflowError (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

I don't understand this stack overflow. More generally, related to my earlier post, I am wondering if someone can present a "correct" version of a fixed point combinator which can be used to approximate fixed points of sequences in this fashion.

Comment: Should the last line perhaps be `(func (* 0.5 x))`?  It looks like it's recurring with the same x forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Brian Carper for his (correct) answer as a comment. The corrected code

```
(defn simple-convergent [func]
  (fn [x]
    (if (zero? x)
      0.0
      (func (* 0.5 x)))))
```

behaves as I expected. My next project is to try to build a fixed point combinator which find unstable fixed points. I don't believe the Y combinator implemented above can do this.